# Is there a script example on how to activate a role in Azure?

Tags: azure

Within Azure AD Privileged Identity Management > My Roles > Azure resource roles

My role only lasts for 8hrs once activated. and takes 1hr give me access to my dashboard. I want to automate this step with a script that does it for me every morning before work. I tried selenium but didn't work. Does someone know a way to do this?

Comment: role lasts 8hr? wth is that?

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Graph API to self activate the role as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/privilegedrole-selfactivate?view=graph-rest-beta).

You can test this out in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and automate it as needed.